# SQL: list rows that do not have any transactions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for definition - def

```
Id        Device            Location
1         GGHY199           USA
12        DFGHY71           India
145       APPHY75           USA
```

And its transactions are recorded in a diff table -event

```
eventid        deviceid         event                date
123              12             Login              12-01-2019
32               12             Unreachable        18-02-2019
223              145            Unreachable        19-02-2019
334              1              DOWN               01-03-2019
```

I want an output as 
for every day, all three devices should show, if it has no transacion, it should show as null, with what i assume is the first date of the month in the date column.
like,

```
eventid        deviceid         event                date
null             1              null               01-01-2019
123              12             Login              12-01-2019
null             145            null               01-01-2019
null             1              null               01-02-2019
32               12             Unreachable        18-02-2019
223              145            Unreachable        19-02-2019
334              1              DOWN               01-03-2019
null             12             null               01-03-2019
null             145            null               01-03-2019
```

currently im doing:

```
select * from def
left join 
event on def.id=event.deviceid
```

and im obviously not getting what i want.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't _eventid_ a primary key in the _event_ table? If it is, then how can there be an event with date and without id?

Comment: i do not want to push this data inside any table, and it wouldn't affect me if the event id doesn't have any value as well. this is just an idea of how i want  my outcome to be. and it only depends on all the device names coming up everyday. im not sure how i should coin my eventid.

Comment: Could you explain which is the relationship between your sample data and expect result?

Comment: you need  a relation with the list of the date  you looing for  ..

Comment: @D-Shih, the sample data has the definition in a table and a transaction in another. they are related with a deviceID. I am trying to graph my data to show the status of every device everyday. when null, ill show active. otherwise, what the transaction states.

Comment: @scaisEdge so will a  month table work out if it helps?

Comment: if you need  only an entry for month yes .. if you need  all the day of the month you need  a full calendar table for your range ..

Comment: @scaisEdge could you help me with how im going to put this all together? say i create a calendar table, should i make a row id? and how will i join it here?

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a valid calendar table for all the date you need  (mimic by the select union all  table t) you could try using left join between calendare and the others  table

```
select t.date, e.eventid, e.device, e.event, d.device
from (
  select   '2019-01-01'  date 
  union all 
  select   '2019-01-02' 
  union all 
  select   '2019-01-03' 
  .....
  union all 
  select   '2019-03-31' 
) t 
left event e on t.date = e.event 
left join device d  on e.device = d.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be after something like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(event_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,device_id INT NOT NULL
,event VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(123, 12,'Login','2019-01-12'),
( 32, 12,'Unreachable','2019-02-18'),
(223,145,'Unreachable','2019-02-19'),
(334,  1,'DOWN','2019-03-01');

 SELECT DISTINCT z.event_id
               , x.device_id
               , z.event
               , y.date 
            FROM my_table x 
            JOIN my_table y 
            LEFT 
            JOIN my_table z 
              ON z.device_id = x.device_id 
             AND z.date = y.date 
           ORDER 
              BY date
               , device_id;
+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| event_id | device_id | event       | date       |
+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|     NULL |         1 | NULL        | 2019-01-12 |
|      123 |        12 | Login       | 2019-01-12 |
|     NULL |       145 | NULL        | 2019-01-12 |
|     NULL |         1 | NULL        | 2019-02-18 |
|       32 |        12 | Unreachable | 2019-02-18 |
|     NULL |       145 | NULL        | 2019-02-18 |
|     NULL |         1 | NULL        | 2019-02-19 |
|     NULL |        12 | NULL        | 2019-02-19 |
|      223 |       145 | Unreachable | 2019-02-19 |
|      334 |         1 | DOWN        | 2019-03-01 |
|     NULL |        12 | NULL        | 2019-03-01 |
|     NULL |       145 | NULL        | 2019-03-01 |
+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: this could work but its generic to the data rows. My data is just the sample set from the actual data and inserting too many values may get tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTE table`, we can create dates and then join them with event table.

```
with t0 (i)    as (select 0  union all  select 0  union all  select 0),
     t1 (i)    as (select a.i from t0 a ,t0 b ),
     t2 (i)    as (select a.i from t1 a ,t1 b ),
     t3 (srno) as (select row_number()over(order by a.i) from t2 a ,t2 b ),
     tbldt(dt) as (select dateadd(day,t3.srno-1,'01/01/2019') from t3)   
select eventid, deviceid, event, tbldt.dt 
from tbldt
left join event e on e.date = tbldt.dt
left join def d  on e.deviceid = d.id 
where tbldt.dt <= (select max(date) from event)
```